# Shopify Liquid: break long string into different lists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify, liquid

I have this long string I get in the Note_Attribute and would like to break it into different lists I can loop through. Here is a sample of what I get:

```
"name": "cancelCase",
"value":"order_id:1542 lineid:4435897659875,quantity:5 lineid:4435894568957,quantity:2"
```

What I am trying to achieve is to convert that value into multiple lists, with each list containing `lineid` and `quantity` values.

Thanks everybody,

Comment: Will the string always have the same format?

Comment: Yes, it is always going to be formatted that way....

Comment: And these are backslashes right? Between 1542 and lineid?

Comment: Yes but they get returned as spaces. I will update the code...

Comment: It looks like you could use the `split` filter on the comma to get an array of pieces that you could then loop through and parse into order_id and lineid parts...  Do you have access to the code that generates this, and are you tied to using the note field? If you can set these as order attributes rather than as the order note, it might be easier to do what you need.